# help to change some colors (woocomerce and store locator)

Tags: customization, woocommerce-offtopic

1. I need to change the background color of the description on the main page of the Woocomerce store. I need to remove the white squares.

[image: woocomerce shop page:]
 2. I have installed store locator plugin and would like to change the background color of the search information box (the grey box). I've already put a custom CSS map, but the code doesn't change the background color. Is this possible?

[image: change the grey color of search box]

Comment: You will have to share the code that is generating that page or the page itself in order to be able to check it.

Comment: sorry for the delay. Here is: http://pepilucasavegana.cl/producto/fresco/

I want to change the white square behind the product description in the related products in woocomerce

Comment: add this to your css: .woocommerce ul.products li.product .desc {
    background: none;
}

Comment: I hope you remember me when you are able to up vote xD